# Recursive Reverse Single Linked List

Tags: c++, recursion

I am trying to just write a basic function that reverses a singly-linked list which is recursive. I was wondering if i tackled this in the right approach? Maybe someone can give me some pointers.

```
 void reverse(Node*& p) {
  if (!p) return;
  Node* rest = p->next;
  if (!rest) return;
  reverse(rest);
  p->next->next = p;
  p->next = NULL;
  p = rest;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: A few seeming mistakes in your code. Node * &p should simply be Node * p. Plus i doubt your assignment p->next->next = p. Basically your current should point to previous and previous should point to current. Before this you should have saved pointer to next to advance further in list

Answer (score 7):

That's not the most efficient way, but to do it, you can call the reverse method with the "next" pointer until there is no next. Once there, set next to previous. After returning from the recursion, set next to previous. See the [recursive version here](http://www.mytechinterviews.com/reverse-a-linked-list) for an example. From the link:

```
Node * reverse( Node * ptr , Node * previous)
{
    Node * temp;
    if(ptr->next == NULL) {
        ptr->next = previous;
        previous->next = NULL;
        return ptr;
    } else {
        temp = reverse(ptr->next, ptr);
        ptr->next = previous;
        return temp;
    }
}
reversedHead = reverse(head, NULL);
```

Comment: OP makes a point of saying "recursive" and you say "non-recursive". Not exactly responsive.

Answer (score 4):

This might be helpful

```
List
{
public:

    .....

    void plzReverse()
    {
         Node* node = myReverse(head);
         node->next = NULL;
    }

private:

    Node * myReverse(Node * node)
    {
        if(node->next == NULL)
        {
            head = node;
            return node;
        }
        else
        {
            Node * temp = myReverse(node->next);
            temp ->next = node;
            return node;
        }
     }
}
```

Another solution might be:

```
List
{
public:
.....

    void plzReverse()
    {
        Node* node = myReverse(head, head);
        node->next = NULL;
    }

private:

    Node * myReverse(Node * node, Node*& rhead)
    {
        if(node->next == NULL)
        {
            rhead = node;
            return node;
        }
        else
        {
            Node * temp = myReverse(node->next,rhead);
            temp ->next = node;
            return node;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: You can edit and merge both answers. also you can take your time to explain why it asnwers the question

Comment: How do i merge these 2 comments. I am new here so i know very little about this site. Regarding explanation: As this code recursively reverse single linked list, I think this will help.

Comment: thnx for merging idea .. now i knoow how to do it

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need:

```
Node* reverse(Node* p) {
  if (p->next == NULL) {
    return p;
  } else {
    Node* t = reverse(p->next); // Now p->next is reversed, t is the new head.
    p->next->next = p; // p->next is the current tail, so p becomes the new tail.
    p->next = NULL;
    return t;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The recursive solution can look quite pretty, even in C++:

```
Node* reverse(Node* pivot, Node* backward = 0) {
  if (pivot == 0)  // We're done
    return backward; 
  // flip the head of pivot from forward to backward
  Node* rest = pivot->next;
  pivot->next = backward;
  // and continue
  return reverse(rest, pivot);
}
```

Most C++ compilers do tail call optimization so there's no reason to believe this to be less efficient than an iterative solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
linkedList *reverseMyNextPointer(linkedList *prevNode, linkedList *currNode)
{
    linkedList *tempPtr;
    if(!currNode)
        return prevNode; 
    else
    {
        tempPtr = currNode->next;
        currNode->next = prevNode;
        return reverseMyNext(currNode,tempPtr);
    }
}

head = reverseMyNextPointer(nullptr,head);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that preserves return value as void.

```
void reverse(Node*& p) {
  if (!p) return;
  Node* rest = p->next;
  if (!rest) {
      rest = p;
      return;
  }
  reverse(rest);
  p->next->next = p;
  p->next = NULL;
  p = rest;
}
```